# Total the results of a subquery in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a query that produces the detailed data I need.

Now I need to change the results to produce a single total by `dbo.Contract.Description` and `dbo.PMTask.Description` instead of the individual entries that would comprise the total.

Here's what I have that works:

```
SELECT        dbo.Contract.Description, dbo.PMTask.Description, 
                         CAST(dbo.PMTimeActivity.TimeBillable AS decimal(10, 2)) / 60 *
                             (SELECT        SalesPrice
                               FROM            dbo.ARSalesPrice AS ARSalesPrice_1
                               WHERE        (InventoryID = dbo.InventoryItem.InventoryID) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.Date >= EffectiveDate) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.Date <= ExpirationDate) AND (dbo.InventoryItem.CompanyID = CompanyID)) AS Amount
FROM  dbo.InventoryItem
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.PMTask
INNER JOIN dbo.Contract ON dbo.PMTask.CompanyID = dbo.Contract.CompanyID AND dbo.PMTask.ProjectID = dbo.Contract.ContractID
INNER JOIN dbo.PMTimeActivity ON dbo.PMTask.CompanyID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.CompanyID AND dbo.PMTask.ProjectID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.ProjectID AND dbo.PMTask.TaskID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.ProjectTaskID
ON dbo.InventoryItem.CompanyID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.CompanyID AND dbo.InventoryItem.InventoryID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.LabourItemID
WHERE (dbo.PMTimeActivity.IsCorrected = 0) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.IsBillable = 1) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.Billed = 0) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.DeletedDatabaseRecord <> 1)
```

How do I change the query such that when I add the following `Group By` I achieve what I want?

```
Group By dbo.Contract.Description, dbo.PMTask.Description
```

Any suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you correct your query such that it works (there is a missing join table) then just add an outer query which sums the amount and groups as specified e.g.

```
select ContractDescription, TaskDescription, sum(Amount)
from (
  SELECT dbo.[Contract].[Description] ContractDescription, dbo.PMTask.[Description] TaskDescription
    , CAST(dbo.PMTimeActivity.TimeBillable AS decimal(10, 2)) / 60 * (
      SELECT SalesPrice
      FROM dbo.ARSalesPrice AS ARSalesPrice_1
      WHERE (InventoryID = dbo.InventoryItem.InventoryID) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.[Date] >= EffectiveDate) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.[Date] <= ExpirationDate) AND (dbo.InventoryItem.CompanyID = CompanyID
    )) AS Amount
  FROM dbo.InventoryItem
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.PMTask
  INNER JOIN dbo.[Contract] ON dbo.PMTask.CompanyID = dbo.[Contract].CompanyID AND dbo.PMTask.ProjectID = dbo.[Contract].ContractID
  INNER JOIN dbo.PMTimeActivity ON dbo.PMTask.CompanyID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.CompanyID AND dbo.PMTask.ProjectID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.ProjectID AND dbo.PMTask.TaskID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.ProjectTaskID
  /* What should go here */  ON dbo.InventoryItem.CompanyID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.CompanyID AND dbo.InventoryItem.InventoryID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.LabourItemID
  WHERE (dbo.PMTimeActivity.IsCorrected = 0) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.IsBillable = 1) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.Billed = 0) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.DeletedDatabaseRecord <> 1)
) X
group by ContractDescription, TaskDescription;
```

Comment: Thank you Dale. Now that you point it out I see what you mean. The second on is an error on my part.

Adding the outer query was the piece I needed to allow me to achieve my goal. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping sets with an empty set will give you a grand total for your groupings, you could use instead cube however that will also generate sub totals for each of your grouped columns as well.

```
SELECT        dbo.Contract.Description, dbo.PMTask.Description, 
                         CAST(dbo.PMTimeActivity.TimeBillable AS decimal(10, 2)) / 60 *
                             (SELECT        SalesPrice
                               FROM            dbo.ARSalesPrice AS ARSalesPrice_1
                               WHERE        (InventoryID = dbo.InventoryItem.InventoryID) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.Date >= EffectiveDate) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.Date <= ExpirationDate) AND (dbo.InventoryItem.CompanyID = CompanyID)) AS Amount
FROM            dbo.InventoryItem RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.PMTask INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Contract ON dbo.PMTask.CompanyID = dbo.Contract.CompanyID AND dbo.PMTask.ProjectID = dbo.Contract.ContractID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.PMTimeActivity ON dbo.PMTask.CompanyID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.CompanyID AND dbo.PMTask.ProjectID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.ProjectID AND dbo.PMTask.TaskID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.ProjectTaskID ON 
                         dbo.InventoryItem.CompanyID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.CompanyID AND dbo.InventoryItem.InventoryID = dbo.PMTimeActivity.LabourItemID
WHERE        (dbo.PMTimeActivity.IsCorrected = 0) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.IsBillable = 1) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.Billed = 0) AND (dbo.PMTimeActivity.DeletedDatabaseRecord <> 1)
Group By Grouping Sets (dbo.Contract.Description, dbo.PMTask.Description, ())
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Dwight, I appreciate your help.

Thanks for the cube suggestion. Unfortunately, when the cube includes grand totals it creates a problem with using it with the other pieces of the solution.

Comment: No problem at all always happy to help if I can. Yeah I thought cube might not be appropriate for what you needed. What about grouping sets in the way suggested in the answer? Did that bring you any closer?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Dwight. In this particular case your suggestion wasn't applicable but I am certain that I will return to the idea at another time when the subtotals and grand totals are what I need.